# adding images dynamically jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add images dynamically to a page. My html contains following lines of code:

```
   <div class="figuredisplay"></div>
```

My css contains following lines of code:

```
.figuredisplay {
  width:350px;
  height:600px;
  padding:10px;
  border:5px solid gray; 
 }
```

Now, I am dynamically obtaining image locations, and trying to add those images in 'figuredisplay'. I am using jquery to do that. So, my code is like:

```
show_figure= function(figrlocation){
  $('.figuredisplay').empty();
  var figrhtmlcode='<img src="' + figrlocation + '" width="300" height="300">';
  $('.figuredisplay').append(figrhtmlcode);
 }
```

but no image is being displayed in the div. When I tried

```
 $('.figuredisplay').append(figrlocation);
```

it displayed the figure location (on disk) correctly on the div element. After doing a bit of search, I tried

```
$('<img src="'+ figrlocation +'">').load(function() {
  $(this).width(300).height(300).appendTo('.figuredisplay');
 });
```

as well, with no luck. Can any one point what I am doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: works for me .. http://jsfiddle.net/errYD/

Answer (score 1):

Try using .html() instead of append.

So it would be something like this:

```
var img = '<img src="image.jpg" width="300" height="300">';

$('.figuredisplay').html(img);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
show_figure= function(figrlocation){
  $('.figuredisplay').empty();
  var figrhtmlcode='<img src="' + figrlocation + '" width="300" height="300">';
  $('.figuredisplay').append(figrhtmlcode);
 }
```

This code should work. Are you sure that figrlocation is not undefined. Check your console for errors.

Comment: figrlocation is defined. I am calling show_figure from a function a, which is called from another function b. function b connects to a database, and function a displays the results from b, creating a button to display the image associated with the result. Is the context lost in some way? Because I am seeing a flash sometimes. But what confuses me is that the same process works just fine while appending text instead of image.

Comment: Can you show the a and b functions? It's unclear what seems to be the problem just looking at 3 lines.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to post the code somewhere and send the link. This place is too small.

Comment: if you see following files: [link](https://gist.github.com/4014339), in reuters.theme.js, in AjaxSolr.theme.prototype.result = function (doc, snippet), I am trying to create a link with every result I obtain from a Solr index, which is handled by reuters.2.js. When I click the link, I want to see the image (the show_figure is called with image location) on the div element figuredisplay. The image, or any text whatever I try to append, vanishes after being displayed for a small time. Can you please look into this?

Answer (score 0):

**I will be using jQuery, find it here: http://jquery.com/download/**
**I accomplish this by cycling through images in a folder all named *pic* (ex. pic1.jpg , pic2.jpg , pic3.jpg , etc...)**

How I have done this in the past was by simply adding two functions to the images.
The first being `onLoad`

- This will let us call our function to add the next image

The second being `onError`

- This will let us call our function to stop loading images (because we have run out of them)

To start, here are the variables that we will use:

```
var preSrc = "/images/pic";     // This gives the first part of the path to the images
var n = 1;                     // This will be which image we are on (denoted by #)
var fileType = ".jpg";        // The file type for your images

// Now put it all together 

var imgSrc = preSrc + n + fileType; // This is the full source for your images

// Now add the rest of the html to be appended

var img = '<img src="' + imgSrc + '" onLoad="nextImg(' + n + ');" onError="stopLoad(this);" />';
```

So what is happening here?
We the first few variables are rather self explanatory, we are just creating the source of our images. The last variable here is a bit more difficult though. We are creating a variable called *img* that will hold the actual html tag that will be added to the document. It also holds data for what the current image is(n).

It also has two attributes to it that I would like to talk about.
The first being the `onLoad` function:

- Here we call a function named `nextImg`. We will create this funciton in a moment, but for now just know that it will ready and publish the next image in our folder to the page.

The second being the `onError` function:

- Here we call a function named `onError`. This is definitely not the *best* way to stop loading the images, but it is the only one that I personally have found that can work with plain javascript. Again, we will create this is a moment, so just know that this will stop loading the images when we run out of them.

Now that we have our the sources for our images taken care of, we need to write the functions that will add our images to the page. This function can be called in a few different ways, but I will stick to one right now.

```
//When the document is loaded, this function will be called

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Create the variables in this function so we can use them
    var preSrc = "/images/pic";
    var n = 1;
    var fileType = ".jpg";

    var imgSrc = preSrc + n + fileType;

    var img = '<img src="' + imgSrc + '" onLoad="nextImg(' + n + ');" onError="stopLoad(this);" />';

    $('#imgContainer').append(img); // Here we use jQuery to append our image to a container with the id of "imgContainer" (This can of course be changed)
});
```

So now that our first image is being loaded when the page is ready, we can create our "onLoad" function:

```
// Here we create our "nextImg" function and create the variable called "currentImg" which will tell us what image was just loaded on the page  
function nextImg(currentImg) {

    //Create the variables in this function so we can use them
    var preSrc = "/images/pic";
    var n = currentImg++; // We add 1 to the current image number so that we can publish the next image in the folder to our page
    var fileType = ".jpg";

    var imgSrc = preSrc + n + fileType;

    var img = '<img src="' + imgSrc + '" onLoad="nextImg(' + n + ');" onError="stopLoad(this);" />';

    $('#imgContainer').append(img); // Now that we have incremented our image number, this statement will now add the next image in our folder to the page.
}
```

Two down, one to go!
Now let's start work on our last function, `onError`.

```
// Here we have the same setup as the last function except for the name
function stopLoad(currentImg) { 

    // Now we simply make sure that there is no "broken image" link left on the page
    $(currentImg).css('display', 'none');
    $(currentImg).css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

Hope this helped, if you have any questions or suggestions (I am sure there are much better ways to do this), then feel free to let me know!

Comment: Improve the readability. Break down the wall of text and use the formatting tools available to improve it.